# Identify appropriate variance stabilization transform

Tags: statistics, variance

I have a heavy tailed data which is heteroscedastic in nature. I need to apply some ML algorithms on this data that are good for normal distribution. So I want to transform the data. I tried Box cox transformation, square root and log transformation but it does not help much and the data still retains its heavy tailed and heteroscedastic nature. What are some of the other variance stabilizing that can be of help here.

Comment: good question. Can you tell more regarding your method and data?

Comment: @Peter I am analyzing time series data. I analyzed heteroscedasticity using bptest method in R. But before and after transformation, the p values remains less than 0.05. QQ plot of the data also remains almost intact.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/189991/11476 (and [related LambertW posts on cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lambertw)) with examples on how to transform financial return data to a marginal Normal distribution using Lambert W x F transformations (in R w/ the [**LambertW**](https://github.com/gmgeorg/LambertW) package; in Python using the [`pylambertw` module](https://github.com/gmgeorg/pylambertw).

Though recall that just transforming to Normality alone does not solve any problem; it depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  Rarely ML algorithms *require* data to be normal (*maybe* conditional on features it should be normal, but even then ML algorithms for prediction purposes often don't really require much distributional assumptions -- unless you want to predict full distributions and/or perform statistical inference & decision making on your ML predicts).  It would be helpful to understand what the actual problem is that you are trying to solve.